# SWIFT: assigning all values of an item in a structure array to a variable

Tags: arrays, swift, variables, struct

Sorry, I don't even have an idea of the keywords to search for answer.

I want to store all items within a global structure to a local variable.

```swift
struct HighScores: Codable {
    var highscoreRecord: [HighscoreRecord]
}

struct HighscoreRecord: Codable {
    var Rank:Int
    var Date:Date
    var avDuration:Float
    var Score:Int
}
```

A global variable is based on this structure and populated within a UIViewController

```swift
var jsonResult: HighScores?
```

Now, in another UIViewController, I want to extract the values of Score for all Highscores and store it to a local variable. I thought it should look somewhat like this, however, I do not get it to work

```swift
@IBDesignable class ScoreTimeGraphView: UIView {

    var graphScore = jsonResult!.highscoreRecord.Score
```

The declaration above throws "Value of type '[HighscoreRecord]' has no member 'Score'"

Any ideas how to do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`highscoreRecord` is an Array. You can't use `.Score` directly on it because the `Array` type doesn't have a property named `Score`.

However, because it's element type is `HighScore` (which does have the property you want), you can iterate over it and collect the `Score` property from each one.

I think this is what you are after:

```
    var allGraphScores = jsonResult!.highscoreRecord.map { $0.Score }
```

[`.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) takes a closure with one parameter, and passes in each element of a sequence in turn.

So, `highscoreRecord.map { $0.Score }` returns a new array, by finding the `Score` property of each `HighScoreRecord` in the array `highscoreRecord`.

<sup>PS it's probably a good idea to name your variables using lowercase [camelCase](https://medium.com/better-programming/string-case-styles-camel-pascal-snake-and-kebab-case-981407998841), for readability and instant recognition by any Swift dev that `Score` is a variable and not an object.</sup>

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was after! Works like a charm (at least declaring, for results I need further coding :-) ) Good point with the variables within the struct.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the property from an array. You need to provide an index to remove the error. Update this line:

```
var graphScore = jsonResult!.highscoreRecord.Score
```

To this:

```
var graphScore = jsonResult!.highscoreRecord[0].Score
```

Comment: Hi @Frankenstein, the problem is, I want to store all Scores so from highscoreRecord[n] to graphScore. So graphScore will be an array with all scores of any Highscore

Comment: When you're accessing property of a variable in an array you need to provide an index. It wouldn't work as `highscoreRecord.Score`